# Automate FTP upload to an IP address

Tags: upload, ftp, ip

Is there a way to automate an upload of files from my local desktop to an external IP address?

Maybe I can write a program in Java/C# that transfers my files from my the local desktop to an external IP address and schedule that program every day for example?

Is this possible?

Comment: [This has been answered](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1744444/114147) for C# if you want to write it in code.

Answer (score 1):

The magic keyword is **crontab**.

- http://linuxwiki.de/crontab

Comment: p.s. it is "cron", as "chron" is something you put in your pipe ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't specify your OS, I am going to assume a *standard* OS (*nix), so you could proceed like this:

Create a Bash script (say `myuploads.sh`), and in it, you'll automate the uploading of the files of interest to the remote machine.

Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

HOST='1.2.5.7'
USER='us3r'
PASSWD='p4ssword'
FILE_TO_UPLOAD='/path/to/some_file.some'
WHERE_TO_UPLOAD='/remote/path'

ftp -i -n $HOST <<Arul
user ${USER} ${PASSWD}

binary
cd $(WHERE_TO_UPLOAD)
put $(WHERE_TO_UPLOAD)

quit
```

You can then use a standard cron (job scheduler) to schedule when to periodically upload that file, using say a cron entry like this:

```
@daily /path/to/script/myuploads.sh >/dev/null
```

That runs the script once every day at midnight.

Answer (score 0):

You mention C#, so for a [Windows system](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/96269), place the FTP commands in a file:

```
user
<your name>
<your password>
cd pub
bin
mput *
quit
```

And schedule a job to run `ftp -n -s:cmd.file 127.0.0.1`.